# hibernate and delete all

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-delete

What is the best way to **delete all rows in a table in Hibernate**?

If I iterate over a collection and call `session.delete()` it's not performing to my knowledge.

If I use another option `session.createQuery("delete ...")` it doesn't affect persistence context.

When I should use these methods if there is no better variant?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

- if you don't have anything to cascade, use the HQL delete `DELETE FROM enityName`
- if you have cascades, iterate the collection and delete each one individually.

The problem lies in the fact that hibernate handles cascades internally, rather than leaving this to the database. So sending a query won't trigger the internal cascades, hence you will have inconsistencies / orphans.

If performance is so crucial (after all it's not everyday that one truncates a table), then you can have more than 1 HQL delete for each cascade - i.e. handling the cascades manually.

Answer (score 28):

You can use HQL for truncate table

```
public int hqlTruncate(String myTable){
    String hql = String.format("delete from %s",myTable);
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql)
    return query.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it

Comment: You have to write the name of java class file in query not table.

Comment: Does not cascade deletes and thus may violate fk constraints.

Comment: This is not a truncate.

Answer (score 10):

```
String stringQuery = "DELETE FROM tablename";
Query query = session.createQuery(stringQuery);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: why is it better to use createQuery than iterate over the collection and call session.delete()? Couldn't I have problem with persistence context?

Comment: @feiroox: It is better because when you iterate over Collection and call delete, it will delete one and one row. This is a big performance issue. However, like Bozho says, if you have cascades, you would perhaps want to do this like that.

Comment: As mentioned above this doesn't handle cascades. I don't know if it is possible to emphasize that more strongly.  I once wasted a lot of time because I assumed that running the HQL would handle cascades.  It IS Hibernate Query Language after all.  But, sadly, it doesn't.  You have to do a session.delete() but this does issue a SQL statement for each individual record which IS very inefficient.