# Hibernate: delete all entities with associations at once

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I want to implement `deleteAll` method that will be delete all `User` entities with their associations, at the same time I want to prevent `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` exception when fetching users collection in memory heap.

My current implementation looks like the code snippet below:

```
public void deleteAll() {
    final int PAGE_SIZE = 15;
    final int PAGE_NUMBER = 0;
    final String SORTING_PROPERTY_NAME = "id";
    List<User> result;

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc(SORTING_PROPERTY_NAME));
    criteria.setFirstResult(PAGE_NUMBER);
    criteria.setMaxResults(PAGE_SIZE);

    do {
        result = criteria.list();
        result.forEach(session::delete);
    } while (result.size() == PAGE_SIZE);
}
```

As you see I am using pagination approach so I fetched one bulk of data then delete it and so on. How this is achieved in reality with Hibernate? Thank you for help.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492453/hibernate-and-delete-all. Could be helpful. Current approach looks quite inefficient, you have to read the entire table then delete each record, too many DB queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("delete from User").executeUpdate();
```

You don't need to fetch all records (or any part) to delete them.
Also look [here](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-basics-3-ways-to-delete-an-entity-from-the-datastore). Maybe it will be useful.

Unfortunately, this approach will not trigger cascade removal. Maybe you can approve another approach. For example, create additional column "is_deleted" and set value true if it is removed. After this you can schedule a job at night. This job will actualy remove some part of these users by your approach. But you will have to add a condition to your get\fetch methods to take into account only is_deleted=false users.

Comment: I realized that my approach (described in question) is a low performance because to many calls to db. So I will use hsl for table truncate. But with this approach in case association like many-to-many I am forced to use native sql query for truncating association table. Thanks Aliaksandr Budnikau and Vladimir Vagaytsev for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use hql or jpl to do this, assuming there are no cascades.

`public int hqlTruncate(String user){
    String hql = String.format("delete from %s",user);
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql)
    return query.executeUpdate();
}`